# Splicing Vinyl Fence Posts Together

Tags: fence, vinyl

I want to heighten my existing 4 ft vinyl fence to 6 ft. I figured every thing out except how to splice an additional 2 ft of post on top of the existing ones. An internal vinyl coupler set with vinyl glue and screws would be ideal, however, I can't find such a thing after searching the internet for days.  Any ideas ?

Comment: Vinyl posts are often installed over wooden 4x4 posts or metal bases. Are yours? We need some detail.

Comment: Mine are hollow, allowing for the bottom, mid, and top rails to be inserted into them.

Comment: Are you sure they're vinyl? They may be a composite. Please add detail, including inside dimensions, *to your question*.